# \lcnamecrefs for subsections

Tags: cleveref

I use the `cleveref` package with the option `capitalise`. At one point I'd like to use the lowercase version of a subsection name, so I tried `\lcnamecrefs`. This works fine for sections, but for subsections it produces the following error message:

```
! Argument of \MakeUppercase has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.10 \lcnamecrefs{sec:test}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\crefname{subsection}{Subsection}{Subsections}

\begin{document}

\lcnamecrefs{sec:test} not working: should be subsections

\namecrefs{sec:test} works correctly: Subsections

\cref{sec:test} works correctly: Subsection 0.0.1

\subsection{test}
\label{sec:test}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add an explicit uppercase definition so that cleverref doesn't build it with `\MakeUppercase`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\Crefname{subsection}{Subsection}{Subsections}
\crefname{subsection}{Subsection}{Subsections}

\begin{document}

\lcnamecrefs{sec:test} works correctly: subsections

\namecrefs{sec:test} works correctly: Subsections

\cref{sec:test} works correctly: Subsection 0.0.1

\subsection{test}
\label{sec:test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Works great!